# jQuery live right click

Tags: jquery, live, right-click

How can i use the jQuery live function as a right click listener?

I've used this plugin: http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/05/jquery-right-click-plugin for right click event listening. But it isn't live, which is a problem for me.

Hope you can help

(btw. sorry for my bad english)

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you insist of using the live function?

Comment: Because i append images via jquery, so i have to use live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rightClick()` is just a function that assigns regular mouse events. The function disables the context menu.

You may be better off just calling `rightClick()` on your images directly in the code that dynamically creates them.

```
var $myNewImage = $('<img src="some/path.jpg" />');
    $myNewImage.rightClick(function(){
                               // Your right click code
                           });

$myNewImage.appendTo(selector);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't gone thru the plugin code but try this out.

```
$("#selector").live("rightClick", function(e) {
     // Do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var $myNewImage = $('<img src="some/path.jpg" />');
$myNewImage.bind("rightClick",function(){
                           // Your right click code
                       });

$myNewImage.appendTo(selector);
```

Or if you like chaining:

```
 var $myNewImage = $('<img src="some/path.jpg" />')
     .bind("rightClick",function(){
     // Your right click code
     })
    .appendTo(selector);
```